# How to capture logged user in the array of users?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

in my CRUD app, the user on the first screen enters their username and then can create, edit, and delete posts. I have an array of users and an array of posts (I'm using Redux). When a user creates a post, their username needs to appear in a sector within the div to identify who posted the post, but I still can't find a way to get the right user who is logged in to show in the div. How could I capture the specific user who is currently logged in?

I thought of doing something like: when the user typed their username and went to the posts screen, all posts would be linked to this user, but I don't know how to do that

postsSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addPost (state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload); 
    },
  editPost(state, action) {
    const { id, title, content } = action.payload;
    const existingPost = state.find((post) => post.id === id);
    if (existingPost) {
      existingPost.title = title
      existingPost.content = content
    }
  },
  postDeleted(state, action) {
    const { id } = action.payload;
    const existingPost = state.some((post) => post.id === id);
    if (existingPost) {
    return state.filter((post) => post.id !== id);
    }
    },
},

});

export const { addPost, editPost, postDeleted } = postsSlice.actions

export default postsSlice
```

usersSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    saveUser (state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload)
    },
  }
});

export const { saveUser, replaceUsers } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice
```

mainscreen.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../_assets/App.css";
import "../_assets/mainscreen.css";
import { MdDeleteForever } from "react-icons/md";
import { FiEdit } from "react-icons/fi";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addPost } from '../redux/postsslice'


import Modal from "../components/modal.jsx";
import EditModal from '../components/editmodal.jsx';

function MainScreen() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user)

  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.loadPosts)
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [buttonGreyOut, setButtonGreyOut] = useState("#cccccc");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (title && content !== "") {
      setButtonGreyOut("black");
    } else {
      setButtonGreyOut("#cccccc");
    }
  },[title, content]);

  const handleSubmitSendPost = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      addPost({
        id: new Date(),
        title,
        content, 
        user
      })
    )
    setTitle('')
    setContent('')
  };

  const handleChangeTitle = (text) => {
    setTitle(text);
  };

  const handleChangeContent = (text) => {
    setContent(text);
  };

  const handleButton = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    navigate("/")
  }

  const [openEditModal, setOpenEditModal] = useState();
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState();

  console.log({ posts })

    return (
      <div className="containerMainScreen">
        <button onClick={handleButton}>Back</button>
        {openModal && <Modal deleteId={openModal} closeModal={setOpenModal} />}
        {openEditModal && <EditModal editId={openEditModal} closeModal={setOpenEditModal} />}
        <div className="bar">
          
          <h1>Codeleap</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="boxPost">
          <h2 style={{ fontWeight: 700 }}>What's on your mind?</h2>
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmitSendPost}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Hello World"
              name="name"
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => handleChangeTitle(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <h2>Content</h2>
            <textarea
              placeholder="Content"
              name="content"
              value={content}
              onChange={(e) => handleChangeContent(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>
            <button
              className="createButton"
              type="submit"
              style={{ backgroundColor: buttonGreyOut }}
              disabled={!title || !content}
            >
              CREATE
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
  
        {posts.slice().reverse().map((post) => (
          <div className="boxPost" key={post.id}>
            <div className="bar">
              <h1>{post.title}</h1>
              <MdDeleteForever
                className="icon"
                onClick={() => {
                  setOpenModal(post.id);
                }}
              />
              <FiEdit
                onClick={() => {
                  setOpenEditModal(post.id);
                }}
                style={{ color: "white", fontSize: "45px", paddingLeft: "23px" }}
              />
            </div>
            <div id="postowner">
                <h3>@{user}</h3>
              <br></br>
              <textarea style={{ border: "none" }} value={post.content}></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default MainScreen;
```

Signup:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "../_assets/signup.css";
import "../_assets/App.css";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import userSlice from '../redux/userslice';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Signup() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  const [buttonGrey, setButtonGrey] = useState('#cccccc')



  useEffect(() => {


      if (name!== '') {
          
          setButtonGrey("black")
      }  

      else {
        setButtonGrey('#cccccc')
        
      }
  }, [name])

  

  const handleSubmitForm= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(userSlice.actions.saveUser(name));
    navigate("/main")
  }
  
  const handleChangeName = (text) => {
    setName(text)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="LoginBox">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}>
        <h2>Welcome to codeleap network</h2>
        <text>Please enter your username</text>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange = {e => handleChangeName(e.target.value)}  placeholder="Jane Doe"  />
        <div className="button">
        <button type="submit" style={{backgroundColor: buttonGrey}}  disabled={!name} >
          ENTER
        </button>

        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

Comment: Did you ever decide how the code decides/knows who the current "logged in user" is? Was the last bit we were looking into?

Comment: Yes, we were in that part... I still can't find a way to define the current user

Comment: Ok, looking at that now in the codesandbox we were working in. You just want to see the posts by the current user, yes?

Comment: Not exactly. All posts should appear normally, but they should be identified correctly, understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a current user and maintain a list of all users that ever "signed in".

user.slice.js

```
const initialState = {
  currentUser: '',
  users: [],
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    saveUser(state, action) {
      // person that just signed in
      state.currentUser = action.payload;
      // list of unique user names
      state.users = Array.from(new Set([...state.users, action.payload]));
    },
    replaceUsers: (state, action) => action.payload
  }
});

export const { saveUser } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice;
```

MainScreen.js

Add an `author` property to each added post, and access the `post.author` property when mapping the posts.

```
function MainScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user); // <-- current user
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.loadPosts);

  ...

  const handleSubmitSendPost = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      addPost({
        id: uuidV4(),
        title,
        content,
        author: currentUser // <-- current user to post
      })
    );
    setTitle("");
    setContent("");
  };

  ...

  if (currentUser === "") {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="containerMainScreen">
        ...

        {posts.map((post) => (
          <div className="boxPost" key={post.id}>
            <div className="bar">
              <h1>{post.title}</h1>
              <MdDeleteForever
                className="icon"
                onClick={() => {
                  setOpenModal(post.id);
                }}
              />
              <FiEdit
                onClick={() => {
                  setOpenEditModal(post.id);
                }}
                style={{
                  color: "white",
                  fontSize: "45px",
                  paddingLeft: "23px"
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div id="postowner">
              <h3>@{post.author}</h3> // <-- user in post object
              <br></br>
              <textarea
                style={{ border: "none" }}
                value={post.content}
              ></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MainScreen;
```

[image: Edit cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-find]